# Retrieve Android purchase information using transaction id using PHP

Tags: php, android

I am using php code to verify a purchase from the playstore using `openssl_pkey_get_public` and `openssl_verify`

Eventually I get a transaction id that looks somewhat like this:
`GPA.1234-1234-1234-12345`

Is there a way to get information about this purchase using PHP that uses that transaction id?

Is there any Android store API out there with this purpose?